# flexbox ios space distribution issues

Tags: html, ios, css, flexbox

Take a look at this image:

[image]

As you can see the 2 end links break out of the anchor container.

This is only happening on an iPad (using simulator to test).

On the desktop it behaves as it should by breaking the words in the other links allowing for more space to distribute the remaining items.

It's as if ios doesn't know how to properly break the text in the first link.

```css
.nav-section {
  padding: 0 30px;
}
.nav-section__list {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.nav-section__item {
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.nav-section__link {
  display: block;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav-section">
  <div class="nav-section__list">

    <div class="nav-section__item">
      <a href="#" class="nav-section__link">AAAAA AAAA-AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA</a>
    </div>

    <div class="nav-section__item">
      <a href="#" class="nav-section__link">AAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA</a>
    </div>

    <div class="nav-section__item">
      <a href="#" class="nav-section__link">AAAAAAAAAAA</a>
    </div>

    <div class="nav-section__item">
      <a href="#" class="nav-section__link">AAAAAAA</a>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>
```

**Update**

- `word-break: break-all` is not a valid solution:

[image]

- `word-wrap: break-all` also doesn't work:

[image]

This is the same resolution but on a desktop:

[image]

As you can see the way the words break is completely different. The iPad just doesn't want to co-operate.

**Update 2**

I have run into the same issue in another instance of flexbox. It seems like IOS still has some bugs with the implementation.

So I went ahead and used `display: table;` and display: `table-cell;` just until the issue is resolved.

If anybody has any other hints as to exactly why the issue might be happening that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for the `word-break` property.

Comment: Sorry I used letters in the example, but in the final version they will be words. I'm  afraid splitting them on a letter level won't fix the issue. All browsers beside IOS treat the issue in the correct manner, smaller and larger in screen size.

Comment: Maybe you can work with the white-space property? Display inline-block on the __link elements maybe does the trick as well. Additionally, I found that using autoprefixer is a bless when working with iOS. Especially iOS 8 needs a lot of prefixes.

Looking at it again; It might be the padding on your items. Move that to the <a> elements. Setting a width (25%) on the item divs could help as well

Comment: save your time, and effort, use @media query and target the iPad on that query, adjust whatever you see works better. Also, Safari 6.1+ supports Flex. You can use -webkit-inline-flex. to work with Safari, Opera, and Chrome. and use -moz- to work with Firefox. (e.g. display: -webkit-inline-flex; )

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox is relatively new, and browsers may have implemented it a little diferently from each other.
You may be missing the `-webkit-`prefix, as it looks like safari did need it on some versions.

```
display: -webkit-inline-flex;
display: inline-flex;
-webkit-align-items: stretch;
align-items: stretch;
```

Or, maybe you could try using:

```
word-break: break-all;
```

To ensure that those words will be broken, and will not overflow.

Comment: On my local version I'm running the css through Autoprefixer, even fully prefixed the issue persists. As for the break-all, because I'm using real words I can't really break them off by the letter. I think there is something else causing this issue as the words break perfectly on desktop browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Must specify  Width in `nav-section__item`

```
.nav-section__item {
  padding: 0 20px;
    word-wrap: break-all;
    width: 20%;
}
```

Live [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/9eo77L4z/)

Comment: Updated the comment to illustrate with what happens to word-wrap. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with safari and flexbox it often helps to just add

```
display: flex;
flex-shrink: 0;
```

to the container which is too small. That should guarantee that the container is atleast the size of its contained element.

Comment: Seems like a comment , not an answer.